# Splitting an integer in python

Tags: python

I'm new to python and trying to build a 10k running calculator from the exercises in "Think Python"

what I'm trying to do is break down the input time ie:43.12 into 2 separate numbers ... 
then perform (43x60)- which gives the seconds and then add the remaining seconds +12 .. 
to give the accurate number to work from ..

below is running it if i hardcode 4312 in as a whole number - but what id like to to accept it dynamically ... can somebody help point me in the right direction

```
#python 10k calculator

import time

distance = 6.211180124223602
time = float(input("what was your time?"))
tenK = 10
mile = 1.61
minute = 60
sph = 0

def convertToMiles():
    global distance
    distance = tenK / mile
convertToMiles()
print("Distance equal to :",distance)


def splitInput():
    test = [int(char) for char in str(4312)]
    print(test)
splitInput()
```

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking here. You're already using `input` to get the time value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier if you don't immediately call convert the user input to a `float`. Strings provide a `split` function, floats don't.

```
>>> time = input("what was your time? ")
what was your time? 42.12
>>> time= time.split('.')
>>> time
['42', '12']
>>> time= int(time[0])*60+int(time[1])
>>> time
2532
```

Comment: This will fail if the input has no seconds component.

Answer (score 1):

You are already converting the number into a float when you ask for it in the input; just accept it as a string and then you can easily separate it into its various parts:

```
user_input = input('what was your time?')
bits = user_input.split('.') # now bits[0] is the minute part,
                             # and bits[1] (if it exists) is
                             # the seconds part
minutes = int(bits[0])
seconds = 0
if len(bits) == 2:
    seconds = int(bits[1])

total_seconds = minute*60+seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have the user input a string in the format `[hh:]mm:ss` then use something like:

```
instr = raw_input('Enter your time: [hh:]mm:ss')
fields = instr.split(':')
time = 0.0
for field in fields:
   yourtime *= 60
   yourtime += int(field)
print("Time in seconds", yourtime)
```

But if you really need a time then you could use time.strptime().

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
time = raw_input("what was your time? ")
x=re.match(r"^(\d+)(?:\.(\d+))$",str(time))
if x:
    time= int(x.group(1))*60+int(x.group(2))
    print time
else:
    print "Time format not correct."
```

Try this way.You can also add some error checking this way.